# IE and mgt-login not coperating

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

Question: why does my color change not work in IE(11) on the mgt-login
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsJr9.png)

```
mgt-login {
    --color: #fff;
}
<mgt-login></mgt-login>
```

Any ideas? It works fine in other browsers

Edit: It's all components i cant change css on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately css custom properties are not supported in IE11:
[image: support]

We are investigating several polyfill options at the moment, feel free to open an [issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues) on the repository if you'd like to track the progress.